# Tag synonym [generic] clashes with use in C

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

Currently the tag [generic] resolves to [generics] on Stack Overflow, which is probably the right thing for object-oriented languages. But since C11, C has a feature `_Generic` which doesn't fit under the same category and is just a compile time `switch` of some sort.

I see two possibilities to resolve that issue

1. Create a tag [_Generic] (if that is possible) to describe exactly the C feature and delete the rename of [generic] -> [generics]
2. Have a proper tag [generic] that talks of type generic programming in a wider range, not only object-oriented languages.

Comment: Generics tags always have generic problems... why don't we just avoid all of them and not use them.

Comment: Does this feature really need a tag? Is [tag:c11] not enough?

Comment: I don't know, but I have seen the flag [generics] wrongly applied.